# Cannot do anything with a corrupt Lake Database table

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I have a corrupt lake database table named `api_endpoints` in Azure Synapse. It was an external table, and I already deleted underlying data from the datalake. I cannot delete the table whatever I try. I presume there is a snippet of metadata which resides in the Hive Metastore - When I query the database:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES order by TABLE_NAME
```

The corrupt table name is still there. I've tried to get rid of this table by trying the following things:

- Simply dropping the table: `spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS api_endpoints")`
- Creating another database, and trying to move the corrupt table there:

  `CREATE DATABASE Junk;`

  `USE raw_UtilityDB;`

  `ALTER TABLE api_endpoints RENAME TO Junk.MyMovedCorruptTable;`

  `DROP DATABASE JUNK Cascade;`
- Trying to overwrite the table using pyspark:

`df = spark.read.csv('random_csv_file.csv')`

`df.write.saveAsTable("raw_UtilityDB.api_endpoints", mode='overwrite')`

Every operation I try results in the exact same error:

```
Error: Cannot recognize hive type string: varchar, column: endpoint_name, db: raw_utilitydb, table: api_endpoints
org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.convertHiveTableToCatalogTableError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:1285)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree2$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:446)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.convertHiveTableToCatalogTable(HiveClientImpl.scala:441)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$getTableOption$3(HiveClientImpl.scala:435)
scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$getTableOption$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:435)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$withHiveState$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:306)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:236)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:235)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:285)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.getTableOption(HiveClientImpl.scala:433)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClient.getTable(HiveClient.scala:90)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClient.getTable$(HiveClient.scala:89)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.getTable(HiveClientImpl.scala:91)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.getRawTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:123)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$getTable$1(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:722)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:102)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.getTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:722)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.getTable(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:138)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.getTableRawMetadata(SessionCatalog.scala:574)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.getTableMetadata(SessionCatalog.scala:559)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2SessionCatalog.loadTable(V2SessionCatalog.scala:65)
org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.DelegatingCatalogExtension.loadTable(DelegatingCatalogExtension.java:68)
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog.loadTable(DeltaCatalog.scala:173)
org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogV2Util$.loadTable(CatalogV2Util.scala:281)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableOrView(Analyzer.scala:1300)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$15.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1294)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$15.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1237)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$3(AnalysisHelper.scala:138)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:138)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1130)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1129)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.DropTable.mapChildren(v2Commands.scala:532)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:1237)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:1203)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:211)
scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:208)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:200)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:200)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:222)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$execute$1(Analyzer.scala:218)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.AnalysisContext$.withNewAnalysisContext(Analyzer.scala:167)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:218)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:182)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:179)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:93)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:179)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:203)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:330)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:202)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:78)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:120)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:207)
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:207)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:78)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:76)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:68)
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:99)
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:97)
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:618)
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:613)
org.apache.livy.repl.SQLInterpreter.execute(SQLInterpreter.scala:129)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session.$anonfun$executeCode$1(Session.scala:680)
scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session.executeCode(Session.scala:677)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session.$anonfun$execute$4(Session.scala:483)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session.withRealtimeOutputSupport(Session.scala:866)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session.$anonfun$execute$1(Session.scala:483)
scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

**How do I get rid of the table?**

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar issues. As last option, you can directly connect to Hive metadata database. Not by spark but by using underlying database connection. This will help you get rid of table forever!

For this you need to;

1- With Hive or Spark, query data location for removing it later (just keep a note, data removal will be last step). This command will print out table details along with table data location.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;
```

2- Connect to metastore DB. It can be any popular database like MySQL, PostgreSQL etc.

> You can find Azure Synapse metastore details in their documentation. [Here is a document for external storages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-external-metastore)

3- Remove all partitions, columns and other table related data via below commands:

```
-- Find `table_id` via below command
select TBL_ID as table_id from TBLS where tbl_name = 'table_name';

-- Remove all related data. ORDER IS IMPORTANT for foreign keys!
delete from TABLE_PARAMS where TBL_ID=table_id;
delete from TBL_COL_PRIVS where TBL_ID=table_id;
delete from TBL_PRIVS where TBL_ID=table_id;
delete from PARTITION_KEY_VALS where PART_ID in (select PART_ID from PARTITIONS where TBL_ID=table_id);
delete from PARTITION_PARAMS where part_id in (select PART_ID from PARTITIONS where TBL_ID=table_id);
delete from PART_COL_STATS where PART_ID in (select PART_ID from PARTITIONS where TBL_ID=table_id);
delete from PARTITIONS where TBL_ID=table_id;
delete from PARTITION_KEYS where tbl_id = table_id;
delete from TBLS where TBL_ID=table_id;
```

4- Finally remove table data from storage.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey - thanks for your answer!! In step 2, while looking at docs: I haven't set up an external hive metastore before. Do i need an azure sql DB for this? Or can I also connect to the one used by Synapse somewhere under the hood? Where can I find it's connection details?

Comment: hmm I am not sure how can you find the managed metastore access. Looks like Synapse doesn't provide it on the UI. I think you can find hive url via  `hive.metastore.uris` spark config key. but this will give you hive application endpoint which is a managed service in your case that you don't have direct access of its resources like its database.

Comment: I think in this case you can open a support ticket. they should be able to help you since its in their control.